# In R Remove ", :/" etc marks from CSV file?

Tags: r, csv

New to R:
I have a csv file with 4 coloumns "Accountnumber" ,"description", "estimatedprice", "negotiatedprice"

I wanted to clean the description and remove marks like ,?!#*[}]}';: how do I do it?

I'm writing the following code but the output table doesnot work.

```
positivefiles <- read.csv('E:/Sanj/text/Second/positive files.csv')
sf <-positivefiles
df <- gsub("[?.;!¡¿·,']/", "", sf)
```

When I do this df is stored as value but not csv file.

I would like to have the cleaned csv file with description without marks.

Please help me on this 
Thank You.

Comment: write.csv(df,"yourCSVname.csv") that will export df to CSV

Comment: Fyi, `[:punct:]` will find all the punctuation.  A bit easier than writing all the punctuation.

Comment: Thank you Steve it did export to CSV in my directory, But it contains only numbers
My Data is 
Accountnumbe    Description        EstPrice    NegPrice
12334         This is small,Order:  50            45

When I export the csv it gives me some random numbers

Comment: Are you trying to remove the `[` and `]`?  If so, they should be preceded by a double-backslash.  [Useful R regex site](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing#Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify to gsub which column in sf you'd like to modify.

Try:

```
df <- sf
df$description <- gsub("[?.;!¡¿·,']/", "", df$description)
```

You may need to adjust your statement to match the correct set of characters you'd like to delete.

Comment: Thank you , This one works but it doesnot have the other columns such as accountnumber, Estdol, Netdol

`df$CLAIM_DESCRIPTION <- gsub("[?.;!¡¿·,:;'/*#@$]", "", df$CLAIM_DESCRIPTION)
write.csv(df$CLAIM_DESCRIPTION, "stack.csv")`

Comment: I got it finally Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Just in case if some one is looking for final code/Experiencing similar problem.**

```
positivefiles <- read.csv('E:/Sanj/text/Second/positive files.csv')
sf <-positivefiles
df <- sf
df$DESCRIPTION <- gsub("[[:punct:]]","",df$DESCRIPTION)
write.csv(df,"cool.csv)
```

**Dictionary :** Cool.csv is my final output file stored in directory

Description is one of my column that is only required to modify.

*Thank you all for input.*